# JAX-WS removes newlines

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, wss4j

I got a problem with a JAX-WS client that tries to invoke a secured service.
I have to sign my message with a X509 certificate, which I do using WSS4J.

Using a custom handler I print the signed messaged to file and everything looks good. The message is divided over three lines, because of the two newline characters in the message signature.
If I copy-paste that message in SoapUI and send it to the server, everything works fine.

But if I send the message directly from the client to the server, I get a SOAPFault that says I don't have a good security header present.

I did some extra tests, like set-up a mock service using SoapUI, and when I receive the message from my client, everything is in a single line. So the newline characters from the signature have been removed, and thus the message is no longer correctly signed.

Anybody has an idea how I can counter this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you use wss4j, have a look at the [documentation for this issue](http://wiki.apache.org/ws/FrontPage/WsFx/wss4jFAQ#Problems+and+errors+with+Signature+verification) - Section `Problems and errors with Signature verification`.

Comment: I don't have a wsdd file, so can I set this option programmatically ?

Comment: I don't think that you need to configure wss4j, what happens is that the XML it signs is different from the XML that gets actually; looks like you have two differently configured XML Marshallers. That or a proxy isn't transparent. I can't help you more than that, I don't have much experience with XML crypto.